# Excel VBA deleting cells that contain certain String Values

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a code that goes row by row checking to see if a certain column in that row contains the string values "Pick-Up" or "Pickup", and if it does delete that entire row. The code I currently have runs, and deletes some of the rows containing said values. But not all of them.

I have tried the AutoFilter method, and for my purposes I do not believe that it will work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
Sub Delete()

Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim testString As String

y = Worksheets("Data").Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

For x = 2 To y
    testString = Worksheets("Data").Cells(x, 27).Value
    testString = Trim(testString)

    If testString Like "*Pick-Up*" Or testString Like "*Pickup*" Then
        Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
    x = x + 1
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to step backwards through your rows, otherwise once something is deleted, your row counter is skipping. E.g. to initiate your loop, use : `For x = y to 2 step -1`

Comment: ALSO you have a line saying `x = x + 1` so you're even telling it skipping rows further unnecessarily!